# Input text from function into label text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, label, iboutlet

I have a function that, for simplicity, let's say gives me the day of the week (it does something else, but that's not important). I used NSLog to verify that the function does in fact give a value, but I can't for the life of me get the text to input and display on the label in the iOS simulator. The relevant code is:

```
-(void)displayLabel {
NSString *result=[self days];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
displayLabel.text=result;
}
```

I have also tried in place of displayLabel.text=result, stringWithFormat, but I think have been getting the syntax wrong:

```
displayLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@":result];
```

The label has an outlet as well as an action in my .h file that looks like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *displayLabel;
}
-(IBAction)displayLabel:(id)sender;

@end
```

Finally, the label itself was placed and kept blank on the view controller in the storyboard. I'm not sure if that has any effect.

So, what am I doing wrong? Can I only display literals? Is my syntax off? What is the correct way of getting the text to display?

Comment: You should check that `displayLabel` is not nil - Set a breakpoint where you update it.  Make sure that you actually connected the label in Image Builder to your IBOutlet

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't cause a crash at all?

Comment: When I use NSLog, it outputs the correct string (for today "Sunday"). It throws no exceptions or anything. In response to Paulw11, do you mean where I reassign its text (displayLabel.text=...)? Also in the interface builder it shows displayLabel connected to DAY TYPE (the current text in my label).

Comment: Put another log in the displayLabel method, NSLog(@"%@", displayLabel) and report what result it gives you.

Comment: @Rick solved it! Although I was being stupid and forgot to add the method to .h. But thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you insist on using the same name for the method and the name of the label, it is always a good practice to name them differently to avoid confusion when troubleshooting for errors later. Test this:

In .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *displayLabel;
@end
```

Create IBOutlet for displaying text in the UILabel and changing its properties. Create IBAction only if you need to interact with the UI and perform certain functions (however, very seldom used on UILabels).

In .m

```
- (void)showDisplayLabel 
{
    NSString *result=[self days];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
    self.displayLabel.text=result;
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Now it's not even printing out the value in the console. Thought it might be because the function was originally called by a button press, so tried that. Prints the value again, but still no change in the label.

Comment: Never mind! Got it, this solved it, just forgot to define the method in .h! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be:

- Is your outlet connected to the storyboard?
- Is your label text color white?
- Is your label width 1 or 0?

Try to check these things, maybe try to create another label with black text inside (it will be overwritten then), just to see if it works.

Comment: I believe so: I put the code in the .h file and then clicked on the view controller, and clicked+dragged the Outlet named "displayLabel" onto the label I'm trying to change. Text color is verified to be black on a red background. Label width is 81 px.

Comment: So everything should be ok. Try to create another label and connect again to the outlet and see if it works

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work. There are no errors coming up in the compiler, but the text is not getting replaced. I'm thinking it has something to do with the way I assign the text. I have an NSString with the correct value being assigned to the label text like this:
    `displayLabel.text=result; //displayLabel is the IBOutlet`

Everything up to assigning the text to the label works. So it either has to be that I connected the label and the IBOutlet wrong, or that something is wrong with my assignment. The IBOutlet looks like this in the .h file: (next comment, ran out of characters).

Comment: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController
    {
    IBOutlet UILabel *displayLabel;
    }
    -(IBAction)displayLabel:(id)sender;

    @end`

The IBOutlet is connected the label on the view controller and the IBAction is connected to a button on the previous page that both flips to the new page and calls the function that checks the day and supposedly reassigns the label text.

Comment: try to define the Outlet in this way in your .m `@property (strong) UILabel *myLabel;` and see if it works connecting this one in the storyboard

Comment: Do you mean `@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel`? Because otherwise I can't connect it. Oh wait, I see, in my .m!

Comment: Still nothing, I put `@property (strong) UILabel *displayLabel` in between `@interface` and `@end`, and then the compiler gave a warning that it would use _displayLabel as the instance variable, so I changed the assignment statement to `_displayLabel.text=...`

Comment: Yep i meant to add `IBOutlet` I just wrote on the fly and forgot it :9 Have you tried the IBOutlet in that way? Then in your code you should use `self.label` or `_label` as the compiler said